# Can I create a reference to a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to create a variable with little code as a reference to another variable so that changing the value of the first variable also changes the value of the second variable? Are there any ready-made classes that make that possible? Or do I have to change the value of the variable by `test.shared.changeMe = true`?

```
class Test {

    var shared: Test = Test()
    var changeMe: Bool = false

    func printValue() {

        print("changeMe: " + String(changeMe))

    }

}
```

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        var reference: Bool = test.shared.changeMe  // <- The variable "reference" should be a reference to the variable "changeMe" of the class test.
        reference = true
        print("Reference: " + String(reference))
        test.shared.printValue()
    }
}

class Test {
    var shared: Test = Test()
    var changeMe: Bool = false
    func printValue() {
        print("changeMe: " + String(changeMe))
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for didSet. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you explained what you want to achieve, what your end goal is? Perhaps you should use notifications or implement the observable pattern or maybe a delegate, hard to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no references for variables, but you can simulate the behavior with a *Computed Variable*.

Computed variables calculate their values instead of storing them, and they are written in the same way as computed properties.  By writing the `get` and `set` to read and write the original variable, you can simulate the behavior you want.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    var reference: Bool {
        get { return test.shared.changeMe }
        set { test.shared.changeMe = newValue }
    }

    reference = true

    print("Reference: " + String(reference))
    test.shared.printValue()

}
```

**Note:** If you need access to `reference` outside of `viewDidAppear`, then declare it as a *computed property* on the class instead (just move it outside of the function).